# How to check if java Subject.doAs method executed in separate thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, action, privileges, subject

I have found that to this method passed

```
  PrivilegedExceptionAction
```

This object has method `run()`. Does it mean that will be created separate thread for executing? Please part of code that create this thread if yes. I didn't find it.

Answer (score 1):

I think maybe this is your answer from SCJP Book:

The overloaded run(String s) method will be ignored by the
Thread class unless you call it yourself. The Thread class expects a run() method
with no arguments, and it will execute this method for you in a separate call stack
after the thread has been started. With a run(String s) method, the Thread
class won't call the method for you, and even if you call the method directly
yourself, execution won't happen in a new thread of execution with a separate
call stack. It will just happen in the same call stack as the code that you made the
call from, just like any other normal method call.

Comment: But I have asked how works from standard jdk. This is not my code.

Answer (score 0):

No, Subject.doAs runs code in the same thread, just with given subject.